# Prevent list lines from running together

Tags: lists, enumerate

I'm trying to build a list of statement forms and when I use the `\land`, etc. command within a list, the list items run together.

I feel like I'm missing something basic.

What do I need to do to have a list item contain commands?

My code:

```tex
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
    \item{p \land q \land r}
    \item{p \land \neg q}
\end{enumerate}
```

My result:

[image]

What I expected:

a) p ^ q ^ r

b) p ^ ¬q

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have loaded `\usepackage{enumitem}` and wrap your math expressions between `\(...\)`.

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
  \item \(p \land q \land r\)
  \item \(p \land \neg q\)
\end{enumerate}
```

Comment: Thanks @roundandroundwego! That was it. I have the package declared but I didn't know about the math expression wrapping. This is my first day using LaTeX and I has having difficulty finding a reference for how to put an expression into a list. Sounds like I should wrap with `\(...\)` even outside of a list, too?

Comment: @ZachB: Yes. Math remains math, inside a list and outside. So wrap it between `\(`...`\)` or `$`...`$`.